# how to update Multiple project in one command

Tags: php, linux, laravel, git, server

I have multiple laravel projects. If I make a custom module for one project and I want that module automatically install to other projects in one way. I don't want to do go to a single project and install modules one by one.. is there any way to update my module in all projects ??

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way, Yes, but the info you are giving is not enough to tell you how. Are they on multiple servers? is the "module" a composer package, if yes, is there a custom package that needs the new package? Have you set up automatic deployment?

Comment: yes, they are on multiple servers. actually, I don't know how to do this. yes module will make on through composer package.

Comment: This seems to be a Laravel framework usage question, not a Linux API, Git command, or PHP programming question...